# Computing product of ith row of array1 and ith column of array2 - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix `M1` of shape `(N*2)` and another matrix `M2` `(2*N)`, I want to obtain a result of `(N)`, each element `i` is the product of `i`th row of `M1` and `i`th column of `M2`. 
I tried to use dot in NumPy, but it can only give me the matrix multiplication result, which is `(N*N)`, of course, I can take the diagonal which is what I want, I would like to know is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ji->i',M1,M2)
```

**Explanation :**

The original loopy solution would look something like this -

```
def original_app(M1,M2):
    N = M1.shape[0]
    out = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N):
        out[i] = M1[i].dot(M2[:,i])
    return out
```

Thus, for each iteration, we have :

```
out[i] = M1[i].dot(M2[:,i])
```

Looking at the iterator, we need to align the first axis of `M1` with the second axis of `M2`. Again, since we are performing `matrix-multiplication` and that by its very definition is aligning the second axis of `M1` with the first axis of `M2` and also sum-reducing these elements at each iteration.

When porting over to `einsum`, keep the axes to be aligned between the two inputs to have the same string when specifying the string notation to it. So, the inputs would be `'ij,ji` for `M1` and `M2` respectively. The output after losing the second string from `M1`, which is same as first string from `M2` in that sum-reduction, should be left as `i`. Thus, the complete string notation would be : `'ij,ji->i'` and the final solution as : `np.einsum('ij,ji->i',M1,M2)`.

**Approach #2**

The number of cols in `M1` or number of rows in `M2` is `2`. So, alternatively, we can just slice, perform the element-wise multiplication and sum up those, like so -

```
M1[:,0]*M2[0] + M1[:,1]*M2[1]
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
In [431]: # Setup inputs
     ...: N = 1000
     ...: M1 = np.random.rand(N,2)
     ...: M2 = np.random.rand(2,N)
     ...: 

In [432]: np.allclose(original_app(M1,M2),np.einsum('ij,ji->i',M1,M2))
Out[432]: True

In [433]: np.allclose(original_app(M1,M2),M1[:,0]*M2[0] + M1[:,1]*M2[1])
Out[433]: True

In [434]: %timeit original_app(M1,M2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop

In [435]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ji->i',M1,M2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop

In [436]: %timeit M1[:,0]*M2[0] + M1[:,1]*M2[1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop
```

Massive speedup there!

Comment: nice answer, let me digest it for a while. einsum is powerful, but seems not easy for beginner to understand.

Comment: could you explain a little bit how this works? I am reading the documentation, it's hard to understand

Comment: @1a1a11a See if the added comments make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is great, both solutions, I tried both, it's worthy to note that the second approach might needs to do np.squeeze(np.asarray(M1[:,0])) and for all following slices, otherwise it may become matrix multiplication and give a `N*N` matrix.

Comment: I am still having a hard time understand einsum, I probably need to read the documentation again.